# angular jest, Testing effect throw Unhandled error

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-test, angular-jest

Here is my effect spec file: when i run this

```
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { Actions } from '@ngrx/effects';
import { provideMockActions } from '@ngrx/effects/testing';
import { cold, hot, getTestScheduler } from 'jasmine-marbles';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import * as TranslationIdAction from './../actions/translationId.action';
import { EffectsTranslationId } from './../effects/translationId.effects';
import { TranslationIdService } from './../../services/translationId-service';
import { ModelTranslationId } from './../../models/model.translationId';

describe('TranslationIdEffects', () => {

    let db: any;
    let effects: EffectsTranslationId;
    let actions: Observable<any>;

    beforeEach(() => {

        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            providers: [
                EffectsTranslationId,
                {
                    provide: TranslationIdService,
                    useValue: { getTranslationIds: jest.fn() }
                },
                provideMockActions(() => actions),
            ]
        });

        db = TestBed.get(TranslationIdService);
        effects = TestBed.get(EffectsTranslationId);
        actions = TestBed.get(Actions);

    });

    describe('check the storage stupport', () => {

        it('should called intial subscribe', () => {

            effects.EffLoadTranslationId.subscribe();
            expect(db.getTranslationIds).toHaveBeenCalled();

        });

    });

});

getting an error as:

jest translationId.effects.spec
  console.error node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/jasmine/Env.js:289
    Unhandled error

  console.error node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/jasmine/Env.js:290
    [
      CallSite {}, CallSite {},
      CallSite {}, CallSite {},
      CallSite {}, CallSite {},
      CallSite {}, CallSite {},
      CallSite {}, CallSite {}
    ]


 RUNS  src/app/pf-services/state/effects/translationId.effects.spec.ts
```

how to fix this?

**my setup-js file:**

```
// import 'jest';
import 'jest-preset-angular';

/* global mocks for jsdom */
const mock = () => {
  let storage: { [key: string]: string } = {};
  return {
    getItem: (key: string) => (key in storage ? storage[key] : null),
    setItem: (key: string, value: string) => (storage[key] = value || ''),
    removeItem: (key: string) => delete storage[key],
    clear: () => (storage = {})
  };
};

Object.defineProperty(window, 'localStorage', { value: mock() });
Object.defineProperty(window, 'sessionStorage', { value: mock() });
Object.defineProperty(window, 'getComputedStyle', {
  value: () => ['-webkit-appearance'],
});

Object.defineProperty(document.body.style, 'transform', {
  value: () => {
    return {
      enumerable: true,
      configurable: true,
    };
  },
});

/* output shorter and more meaningful Zone error stack traces */
// Error.stackTraceLimit = 2;
```

Comment: Can you please show your jest setup ?

Comment: @Suvendu - setup-jest.js file added, please check

Comment: @Suvendu - i have added all connected files here: https://plnkr.co/edit/IyyCAiaBov47Amfgfrgl?p=catalogue

Comment: After a cursory read of you setup, it seems okay to me. Although you might wanna remove the jasmine modules and setup jest like I did. Here is a plunkr for my package.json - https://plnkr.co/edit/QA7c30inyVuAQbd6mKLB?p=catalogue . Hope this helps.